# Generate CLASSPATH string based on maven build

Tags: java, maven, sh, classpath

I have dependencies in my pom.xml like this:

```
<dependency>3.jar</dependency>
<dependency>1.jar</dependency>
<dependency>4.jar</dependency>
<dependency>2.jar</dependency>
```

I have a maven project that when deployed, will have a directory structure like this:

```
myproj/
|_lib/
  |_1.jar
  |_2.jar
  |_3.jar
  |_4.jar
|_start.sh
```

The start.sh loads all the jars in the lib folder like this:

```
CLASSPATH=./lib/*
```

Problem is, when I echo the CLASSPATH, it loads the jars alphabetically:

```
CLASSPATH=/lib/1.jar;/lib/2.jar;/lib/3.jar;/lib/4.jar;
```

I want it to be what maven uses:

```
CLASSPATH=/lib/3.jar;/lib/1.jar;/lib/4.jar;/lib/2.jar;
```

I can do

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt
```

but it prints out the jars in my local repository:

```
CLASSPATH=C:\.m2\repository\com\project\3.jar;\.m2\repository\com\project\1.jar;...
```

I think I can modify the generated output but I am looking for a better solution.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: "*it loads the jars alphabetically*" - why is that a problem? Unless you have the same class in different JAR files (which you shouldn't) the order of the jar files in the classpath is not important

Comment: Actually that was the problem - same class in different jars. And since the jars are proprietary, I have no other choice but to order the classpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `prefix` parameter to `dependency:build`. From [the docs](https://maven.apache.org/components/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/build-classpath-mojo.html):

> **prefix**
>
> The prefix to prepend on each dependent artifact. If undefined, the paths refer to the actual files store in the local repository (the stripVersion parameter does nothing then).
>
> User property is: mdep.prefix.

For example:

```
mvn dependency:build-classpath -Dmdep.outputFile=cp.txt -Dmdep.prefix=/lib
```